# Wrong characters in Developer Survey Results 2016 page

Tags: bug

On the mentioned page :

https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2016

It seems that many single quote characters `'` have been replaced by `â€™` (23 occurences).

I examined the source, and the characters are here verbatim.

example :

> 10% of respondents self-identified as Ninjas. Real ninjas donâ€™t tell
>   you theyâ€™re ninjas. They just sneak up on you and slit your throat,
>   which we're pretty sure constitutes a "hostile workplace environment".

Same behavior on Chrome (63) as on Firefox (57)

Feel free to ask if more details are needed.

Comment: Some straight quotes-to-curly script ran amok. What you see is not random, it's the UTF8 encoding for a curly quote. And then encoded again – a typical n00b error. If SO needs any help with that, they can post on the main site :)

Comment: Strange that this (hypothetical) script only targeted single quotes, though. As your snippet shows, double quotes are unaffected.

Comment: @usr2564301 note that there are *also single quotes* that were unaffected (in same snippet)

Comment: as per the date of this comment, the reported problems are still there.